# What does this mean 'string? message'

Tags: c#

I just came across this looking at the definition for the `PlatformNotSupportedException` class.

What does `string? message` mean. As far as I was are the `?` is short hand for `Nullable<>`, but `Nullable<>` can only be applied to struct's and `string` and `Exception` are classes.

My best guess is its an optional parameter declared like `string message = null`, if thats the case why not just show it and the default value?

```
public PlatformNotSupportedException(string? message, Exception? inner);
```

Comment: C# **8.0** allowes nullable *reference* (like `string`, `Exception`) types, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: here is one more usefull [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/)

Comment: And [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) will be helpful as well

Comment: Nice idea, but it looks like its going to be a significant effort to fix up existing code. Any idea how the reflection model has changed to support it?

Answer (score 3):

It is a way to declare Nullable Reference Types. [The syntax to expect `NULL` in C# 8:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/february/essential-net-csharp-8-0-and-nullable-reference-types)

> To begin, there needs to be a syntax for distinguishing when a
>   reference type should expect null and when it shouldn’t. The obvious
>   syntax for allowing null is using the ? as a nullable declaration—both
>   for a value type and a reference type. By including support on
>   reference types, the developer is given a way to opt-in for null with,
>   for example:

```
string? text = null;
```

In addition, we can declare [non-nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/february/essential-net-csharp-8-0-and-nullable-reference-types):

```
string! text = "It is non nullable"
```